# After Insert Trigger on Microsoft SQL Server -- Updating a column in a newly created record

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, database-trigger

I have 3 tables **Data table, LookUp_1,LookUp_2** all with column **id** which are primary key columns. The **score1_id and score2_id** columns are foreign key columns. score1_id links with **id in LookUp_1** and score2_id links with **id in LookUp_2**.

[image]

**My question is:**
I need to create an **after insert** trigger which will update the calculation column from null to a specific number/value. This only happens when a new record is inserted into the Data table and it only should affect the newly created record. So for the example i have, **id 1** is a newly inserted record, and now the trigger should go on and update the **calculation column** using the **score1_id and score2_id**. So it should go into **LookUp1 and LookUp2** and check the weights for each id. So for example: 3=7 and 2=3. So after the trigger is completed the record should be updated with calculation column = 21 (since we are multiplying the weights)

so the updated table record should look like this:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to go about this?? Or some examples anyone has in mind?

I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: It it only happens on insert, then build that into your insert statement instead of making a trigger?

Comment: @Brad I'm tasked to do a trigger statement only.

Comment: Ok, it just seems inefficient and extra work to do it that way.

Comment: You should lay it out logically. This is the insert. What do you need to do to get from insert to final table. (That is what you program as your trigger). But I agree with Brad, this should be part of the insert and not a trigger. Or if it is just multiplying two columns then make it a calculated field

Comment: @Brad any suggestions how to go about it/

Comment: @KeithL maybe I'm confused on how this actually works. So need a trigger. And then an insert statement in the trigger?

Comment: Not with triggers no, or you could make the calculation on your select when you need to display the data only (and not save the calculation data in the table itself).  What happens if the 2 values you are calcluating on for the insert change?  Is that fine?  So after the insert the values change in the lookup then the multiplied values will not match what is in the table

Comment: Why are you tasked to use a trigger only?   Is this homework for a class?

Comment: @TabAlleman Whenever a new record is inserted to the table, the trigger goes off and calculated the weights from both lookUp tables. Then the value is inserted/updated into the calculation column. The calculation column is null initally.

Comment: @MoizAhmed We all understand that, but if there was a BETTER way to do this than use a trigger, why wouldn't you use it?

Comment: @TabAlleman my supervisor wants to use triger

Comment: I gave you the how to do what you are asking, but do not recommend it. You should really join lookups to data whenever you use it. It is too easy for the calculation to be wrong whenever a weight changes or a lookup changes

Comment: @KeithL score1_id and score2_id in table Data are FK's that are linked with ID columns in LookUp_1 and LookUp_2. Is this what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your trigger (well you need to finish it)

Need to update now that you posted column names.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [triggername]   
ON   [data]

 AFTER    
INSERT   
AS 
BEGIN
    declare @v1 int = (Select weight from lookup1 where id=inserted.scoreid1
        ,@v2 int = (Select weight from lookup2 where id=inserted.scoreid2)

    update data
    set calculation = @v1*@v2
    where inserted.id = data.id
END
```

or for multiple inserts:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [triggername]   
ON   [data]

 AFTER    
INSERT   
AS 
BEGIN
update data
    set calculation = l1.weight*l2.weight
from data d
join lookup_1 l1 on d.scoreID1=l1.id
join lookup_2 l2 on d.scoreid2=l2.id
join inserted on inserted.id = d.id
END
```

Comment: tried the multiple inserts and it works! thank you so much

Comment: I was wondering what this statement exactly does and where its coming from?

Comment: join inserted on inserted.id = d.id

Comment: in a trigger, inserted is a table of the recent inserts that metadata mirrors the affected table. "join inserted on inserted.id = d.id" means only update the inserted records.

Comment: how will i go about doing the trigger if i edit an already existing record and the calculation column happens to change also. From the trigger i have right now, the **calculation** will only calculate for newly inserted records; not old records. Thanks

Comment: Also include UPDATE in your trigger CREATE TRIGGER [triggername]   
ON   [data]

 AFTER    
INSERT   , UPDATE
AS

Comment: so if i want to alter the already existing trigger, should i put a "update" before the "AS"?

Comment: YES ( I am pretty sure that just using UPDATE includes Inserts